# New enumeration

Tags: spacing, lists, indentation, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item  
   \item 
   \item
   \item
\end{enumerate}
```

How to define new numeration: I would like to have bigger spaces between every two points and equal indents for all points.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you consider that one of the answers solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `enumitem` package you can specify the space between items as an optional `itemsep` argument:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=10pt]
  \item%
   Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  \item%
   Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  \item%
   Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The indention is of course the same for all labels.

Answer (score 0):

See the `enumitem` package. Though I do not understand the *and equal indents for all points* comment, that is the default for `enumerate`.

Comment: I would like to accrue a space at the beginning of a line (indentation) in every point (item)